# Save Error: Entity 'Integration' not accessible in version 31.0

Tags: apex, webservices, eclipse, force.com-ide

I try to save a class that wrapps the functionality of a WebService, but after the save it gives me this error: "Save Error: Entity 'Integration' not accessible in version 31.0". Please, any idea, would be helpful.

Thanks, 
Endrit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you are trying to refer to a custom SObject with label = Integration but API name is most likely `Integration__c`. Because the name is used without the `__c`, SFDC thinks it is a standard Sobject but can't find it in the standard SFDC schema using the version of the class you are compiling.

All SObject references in Apex need to use the API name; and for custom objects and fields, these will end in `__c` (or, in the case of relationships, `__r`)

Comment: I my case, I used __Share on object, which doesn't have one.